# Carrierwave object.url VS object.image_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

In my Rails 5 app I am using Carrierwave to upload images.

I have to model that uses the same uploader:

account.rb:

```
mount_uploader :logo, ImageUploader
```

image.rb:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

This uploads the file to:

> "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"

The strange this now is that I can use:

```
@account.logo&.url(:thumb) // works!
@account.logo&.image_url(:thumb) // error!
```

But on the image model (one product has many images):

```
@product.images.first&.image_url(:thumb) // works!
@product.images.first&.url(:thumb) // error!
```

So in the first case I have to use .url and in the second one .image_url

An I have no idea why...any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance method `image_url` is defined dynamically based on the column that is passed to `mount_uploader` and simply calls `url` on the column. The definition looks like this...

```
def #{column}_url(*args)
  #{column}.url(*args)
end
```

So, I would suspect that `logo_url` would work on `@account` (although I have not tested this)

[source](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/57a4a3b65f475ec21b51bba36da13eab9f864a67/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L149)